# Diffrence between JPA API and hibernate native API

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am still a beginner in hibernate.I have started reading the user guide in which i found this architecture.[image]

I know that hibernate is a jpa implementation and the jpa jar contains only interfaces.But i want to understand why JPA API is in the same level as Hibernate native api.
And if JPA contains only Interfaces how can we call for example entityManger.persist(entity) and normaly the entity manager is an interface.
where is the entity manger implementation ???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I know that hibernate is a jpa implementation and the jpa jar contains only interfaces.But i want to understand why JPA API is in the same level as Hibernate native api.

Because you can either use the JPA API (EntityManager, EntityManagerFactory etc) or Hibernate native API (Session, SessionFactory etc) to interact with the ORM entities and the database.

> And if JPA contains only Interfaces how can we call for example entityManger.persist(entity) and normaly the entity manager is an interface. where is the entity manger implementation ???

JPA API like EntityManager, EntityManagerFactory etc are implemented by Hibernate (one of the JPA implementations, other like EclipseLink etc do exist). You will find that implementation in one of the hibernate jar files. .

A quick ref of [Hibernate implementation of EntityManagerFactory here on grepcode](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager/5.0.0.CR3/org/hibernate/jpa/internal/EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java?av=f)